# Jenkins SQLServer Choice Parameter - Retrieve data from database

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, jenkins, groovy

I am trying to get data from SQL Server database table and show it as part of choice parameter as part of a Jenkins Job Build Parameters that I am trying to setup.

I am trying to figure out how to use Extensible Choice for this.
The Choice provider I used is "System Groovy Choice Parameter"

```
import groovy.sql.Sql
import com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver

def output = []

def configuration = [
 'dbInstance' : 'servername',
 'dbPort' : 0000,
 'dbName' : 'dbName',
 'dbUser' : 'dbUser',
 'dbPass' : 'dbPass'
]

def sql = Sql.newInstance("jdbc:sqlserver://${configuration.dbInstance}:${configuration.dbPort};" 
+ "databaseName=" + configuration.dbName, 
configuration.dbUser, configuration.dbPass, 
'com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver')

String sqlString = "SELECT * FROM dbTable"
sql.eachRow(sqlString){ row -> output.push(row[0])
}

return output.sort()
```

Below is the error I see. Which I understand I see because the jdbc driver is not present. I downloaded the driver from the link below:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11774

I followed the instructions as to where it should be unzipped to as mentioned in the instructions.

I saw that the CLASSPATH variable is missing, so i went ahead and created the Environment variable with path: "C:\Program Files\sqljdbc_6.0\enu\sqljdbc.jar"

```
Error: unable to resolve class com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
```

How do i make sure that the script runs successfully and returns all the data to Extensible Choice. If there is anyother way to do this, I am open to suggestions.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the issue I had to copy the "sqljdbc4.jar" file to the following location "C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\jre\lib\ext" since that is the path where the JAVA searches for the external jars. Use 4th version for the file which will have 4 in the file name as above as that is version Jenkins supports.